# Groups claim missing from JWT generated by fusionauth while setting up sso with fusionauth

Tags: docker, single-sign-on, openid, minio, fusionauth

I am trying to link fusionauth as an SSO provider for minio, but facing the following error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?\>
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/"><Error><Type></Type><Code\>InvalidParameterValue\</Code\>\<Message\>groups claim missing from the JWT token, credentials will not be generated</Message></Error><RequestId>175A7B8469F151BB</RequestId\></ErrorResponse\>
```

Upon inspecting the JWT sent by Fusionauth, the payload is

```
{
  "aud": "55ad32c7-99eb-40e9-abc0-479c2f18c18e",
  "exp": 1682796819,
  "iat": 1682793219,
  "iss": "acme.com",
  "sub": "ad58f73f-79fd-4806-86f7-cd9d48b65400",
  "jti": "85e0a440-c254-4684-9c7b-caa830c1d491",
  "authenticationType": "PASSWORD",
  "email": "admin@admin.com",
  "email_verified": true,
  "at_hash": "wLcTvHBgOMQblFXSJCEr2w",
  "c_hash": "N9XJhvfh8Cz0sKnWjw3TEQ",
  "scope": "openid offline_access",
  "sid": "8ed4559c-1d86-41db-9312-cfd2e42d0fc4",
  "auth_time": 1682793219,
  "tid": "42178a6c-35ab-6c81-f8f9-4696fc894a60"
}
```

which is indeed missing the `groups` claim. I have created roles in the application which correspond to minio bucket policy names and also added them to the user I am trying to authenticate. Also I have made a group named minio which has all these roles and it is attached to the user as well. What am I doing wrong? How can I send the role names through the jwt so that mino authenticates with fusionauth?

Sharing my minio OpenID settings here

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAmei.png

I tried adding roles to the user and attached it to the group

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is to use a JWT Populate Lambda to add in the additional claims that you need. The documentation for that is here:

https://fusionauth.io/docs/v1/tech/lambdas/jwt-populate

This should allow you to add the `groups` claim in whatever format is required.

Then, you just need to associate the Lambda with the Application. This is done by editing the Application and clicking on the `JWT` tab. At the bottom of this tab, you'll find the setting named `Access Token populate lambda`. This controls the Lambda that is used to manipulate the JWT.